# Ambiguity function of multiple sines

Tags: autocorrelation

I was reading through the Ambiguity function, and I was wondering if it's possible to calculate analytically (or numerically) the ambiguity function of a sum of sine waves. In case of a single sine wave the envelope is a [rect()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), hence the ambiguity function is a $sinc()$ with variables the delay time and the Doppler frequency. [Here's](http://postimg.org/image/gqvdryc6l/)  the respective 3D plot. Is it possible to perform a similar reasoning for multiple sines?

Answer (score 1):

Sum of sines isn't a concrete waveform, there is no general form of its ambiguity function. But for any given sum of sines you can calculate this function by evaluating cross correlation for various time and Doppler deviations. Though one rule exists, if the number of sinewaves in composition grows, the ambiguity function will become narrower in both frequency and time dimensions, since such a signal will be more and more noise like.

Since autocorrelation isn't linear function of some signal $s$ (its quadratic as you know cause it is sum of multiplications of $s$ and its shifted copy), so you can't express autocorrelation and more generally ambiguity function of sines composition as a sum of their autocorrelations (or amb. func-s.). Actually it is the sum of entering sines' autocorrelation functions and all possible entering sines' cross correlation functions. It could be something huge. So the most general way is to compute of such a function for given sines sum directly with knowing formula of autocorrelation.

Comment: What do you mean by concrete waveform? I guess you mean that the number of sines, amplitudes, frequencies and phases are not fixed.  Is that right?

Comment: How is ambiguity function defined?  Can we have AmF for a trianglurar signal (triangle is not the envelope of some carrier but the signal itself is angular)?

Comment: Yes I mean sum of sines can have arbtrary parameters such as number of sines, frequencies etc. And they are not fixed from one realization to another. We can choose any. Noise-like signals as you know can also be expressed as a sum of sines. You can estimate AmF for any waveform you like. You should find cross-correlation between the original (say reference) signal and its copies with proper Doppler shifts. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity_function for the details.